# VBA Excel importing new rows to file

Tags: excel, vba, ms-office

I am trying to import rows with new data from the Report.xlsx file to my Workbook.xlsx file, based on column X , which can contain a number or numbers separated by a comma. I only have to import the rows that are not already in my workbook, with 69 cells which can contain numbers and text as well. I want this macro to run automatically on a weekly basis. The program runs without any issue, it evens opens and closes the Report file after executing, but the rows are not imported.

```
Sub Weekly_Report()
Const HAS_HEADER As Boolean = True 'Set true if the file has a header(Report)
Const NUM_COLS As Long = 69 '69 rows needed to be imported from the Report

Dim Path, Filename, wbReport As Workbook, wsReport As Worksheet, m
Dim wsData As Worksheet, next_blank_row As Long, r As Long, c As Range, rwStart As Long

Path = "C:\Users\Documents\" 'path of the report
Filename = Dir(Path & "Report.xlsx")

Set wsData = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1") 'for example: destination worksheet
next_blank_row = Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeLastCell).Offset(1, 0).Row + 1 'next blank row

Do While Filename <> ""

    Set wbReport = Workbooks.Open(Path & Filename) 
    Set wsReport = wbReport.Worksheets(1)          
    rwStart = IIf(HAS_HEADER, 2, 1)
    
    For r = rwStart To wsReport.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
        
        m = Application.Match(wsReport.Cells(r, 1).Value, wsData.Columns("X"), 0)
        If IsError(m) Then
            m = next_blank_row 'no match - use next blank row and increment
            next_blank_row = next_blank_row + 1
        End If
        wsData.Cells(m, 1).Resize(1, NUM_COLS).Value = wsReport.Cells(r, 1).Resize(1, NUM_COLS).Value
    Next r
    
    wbReport.Close False
    Filename = Dir()
Loop

End Sub
```

Comment: You have debugged your code and noticed where it behaves different that expected?

Comment: The debuger says no error.

Comment: No, that's the compiler. The debugger helps you execute your code step by step.

Comment: `Set wbReport = Workbooks.Open(Path & Filename)`-run-time error '1004' -Sorry we couldn't find. Is it possible it was moved, renamed or deleted? `Set wsReport = wbReport.Worksheets(1)` -Run-time error '91'-Object variable or with block variable not set-also I get the same error in the for loop

Comment: Is the `Dir`-command successfull? Else `Filename` is empty. Those things can be easily checked using the debugger - you should invest some time to learn and understand how to use it.

Comment: `Filename = Dir()` -for this line - run-time error '5'-Invalid procedure call or argument

Comment: Why are you are matching column A in the report file with column X in Workbook.xlsx ? Do you only have one report file C:\Users\Documents\Report.xlsx ? Should there be a subdir username  eg C:\Users\UserName\Documents ?

Comment: I just deleted the subdir username because of privacy reasons. There is only one report file in that folder. At which point am I matching column X with column A?

Comment: Matching here on this line, the 1 is col A ;  Application.Match(wsReport.Cells(r, 1).Value, wsData.Columns("X"), 0).

Comment: Not it says run-time error '1004'-Unable to get the Match property of the WorksheetFunction class at line: `m = Application.WorksheetFunction.Match(wsReport.Cells(r, 24).Value, wsData.Columns("X"), 0)`

Comment: Is the code you have posted in the question the same as the code you are running ?

Comment: I also added worksheetfunction since then, but apart from that it is the same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As alternative to MATCH try the [Range.Find](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.range.find) function.

```vb
Option Explicit

Sub Weekly_Report()
    
    Const HAS_HEADER As Boolean = True 'Set true if the file has a header(Report)
    Const NUM_COLS As Long = 69 '69 rows needed to be imported from the Report
    Const FILENAME = "Report.xlsx"
    Const PATH = "C:\Users\Documents\" 'path of the report
    
    Dim wbReport As Workbook, wsReport As Worksheet, wsData As Worksheet
    Dim next_blank_row As Long, iStartRow As Long, iLastRow As Long, iRow As Long
    Dim sFilename As String
        
    Set wsData = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1") 'for example: destination worksheet
    next_blank_row = wsData.Cells(Rows.Count, "X").End(xlUp).Row + 1 'next blank row
    
    sFilename = PATH & FILENAME
    Debug.Print "Opening ", sFilename
    On Error Resume Next
 
    Set wbReport = Workbooks.Open(sFilename)
    On Error GoTo 0
    If wbReport Is Nothing Then
        MsgBox "Can not open " & sFilename, vbCritical, "ERROR"
        Exit Sub
    End If
        
    Set wsReport = wbReport.Worksheets(1)
    iStartRow = IIf(HAS_HEADER, 2, 1)
    iLastRow = wsReport.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
        
    Dim s As String, rng As Range, m As Long
    For iRow = iStartRow To iLastRow
        
        s = CStr(wsReport.Cells(iRow, "X").Value)
        Set rng = wsData.Columns("X").Find(s)
        
        If rng Is Nothing Then
            m = next_blank_row 'no match - use next blank row and increment
            next_blank_row = next_blank_row + 1
            Debug.Print iRow, s, "New row " & m
        Else
            m = rng.Row
            Debug.Print iRow, s, "Match row " & m
        End If
        wsData.Cells(m, 1).Resize(1, NUM_COLS).Value = wsReport.Cells(iRow, 1).Resize(1, NUM_COLS).Value
        
    Next
        
    MsgBox wsReport.Name & " scanned from row " & iStartRow & _
           " to " & iLastRow, vbInformation, sFilename
    wbReport.Close False

End Sub
```

Comment: The code says Sheet1 scanned from row 2 to 431 in the Report file after execution. But it gives runtime error '91'-"Object variable or with block variable not set" in line: `next_blank_row = wsData.Cells(Rows.Count, "X").End(xlUp).Row + 1 'next blank row`

Comment: Also none of the rows are imported.

Comment: @Brozoka Where have you located the macro, is it in Workbook.xlsx (sheet, workbook, module ) or another  workbook ? How do you intend to run the macro 'automatically on a weekly basis' ?

Comment: The code seems to be working now. The macro was saved on the personal macros and not the workbook. I will get reports on a weekly basis and I have to do the same process with them(they have the same structure). Thank you for your help! @CDP1802